# Regenerate QR code in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, barcode, qr-code

I am develping an app in iphone which reads barcode using ZBar framework. Is there any framework or sample code to re - generate the bar code or QR code?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) has QR code generating code. It's in Java though, but you could port it -- actually I forget whether it's already been ported within the project.

But, even easier, just call to the [Google Chart Server](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html). It has the same encoder inside it. No coding needed to get an image for given contents.